# how would I be able to replace string values stored in one linked list with string values from another linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I was trying to update the values of the strings stored in a linked list that had English words with Spanish words. I thought I could change the list of English words and later display the updated translated list.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char *engword;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node eng;

struct new {
    char *spanword;
    struct new *next;
};
typedef struct new span;


eng *addEng(const char *word, eng *head)
{
    eng *temp1;

    temp1 = malloc(sizeof(*temp1));

    // add char type word to linked list
    temp1->engword = strdup(word);
    temp1->next = head;
    head = temp1;

    return head;
}

span *addSpain(const char *word, span *head)
{
    span *temp1;

    temp1 = malloc(sizeof(*temp1));

    // add char type word to linked list
    temp1->spanword = strdup(word);
    temp1->next = head;
    head = temp1;

    return head;
}

void eng_display(eng *head){
    eng *current;
    current = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        printf("word linked: %s\n", current->engword);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

void spain_display(span *head){
    span *current;
    current = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        printf("spanish: %s\n", current->spanword);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

void replace(eng *head, span *head1){
    eng *current;
    span *temp;

    current = head;
    temp = head1;

    while(current != NULL){
        current = malloc(sizeof(*current));
        current->engword = (char*)calloc((strlen(temp->spanword)+1), sizeof(char));
        current->engword = temp->spanword;
        printf("translated: %s\n", current->engword);
        current = current->next;
        
    }
    free(current);

}
   
int main(){
    size_t size = 0;
    char *line = 0;
    eng *head;
    head = NULL;

    FILE *fO;
    fO = fopen("english.txt", "r");


    while(getline(&line, &size, fO) != -1){
        
        
        char *name = strtok(line, " ");
        //printf("the word '%s'\n", name);
        while(name != NULL){
            head = addEng(name, head);
            name = strtok(NULL, " ");

        }
    }
    eng_display(head);


    char *nline = 0;
    span *head1;
    head1 = NULL;
    FILE *Madrid;
    Madrid = fopen("span.txt", "r");

    while(getline(&nline, &size, Madrid) != -1){
        
        
        char *w = strtok(nline, " ");
        //printf("the word '%s'\n", w);
        while(w != NULL){
            head1 = addSpain(w, head1);
            w = strtok(NULL, " ");

        }
    }
    spain_display(head1);
    replace(head, head1);
}
```

This program ran using two files.
english.txt

```
you 
are
cool
```

and span.txt

```
tu 
eres
guay
```

When I ran it, it just printed out this:(just from the replace())

```
translated:guay
translated:guay
translated:guay
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to change the English linked list?

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you are accessing unassigned memory in `current` - there are others (read the comments in the code below and see the next section for a correct code)

```
void replace(eng *head, span *head1){
    eng *current;
    span *temp;

    /* 1: You assign head to current but you run over it in 2 */
    current = head; 
    temp = head1;

    while(current != NULL){
        /* 2 Here you just create a new structure */
        current = malloc(sizeof(*current)); 
        /* 2.5 Here you allocate the string but in the next line you just overwrite the pointer */
        current->engword = (char*)calloc((strlen(temp->spanword)+1), sizeof(char));
        current->engword = temp->spanword; /* This line leaks memory */
        printf("translated: %s\n", current->engword);
        /* 3 And your problem is here - current->next is garbage because the old value was overwritten in 2 */
        current = current->next; /* This line leaks memory */
        
    }
    free(current); /* Here you probably free garbage */
}
```

You probably wanted something like this

```
void replace(eng *head, span *head1){
    eng *current;
    span *temp, *temp1;

    current = head; 
    temp = head1;

    while(current != NULL){
        /* Free the old value */
        if (current->engword != NULL)
            free(current->engword);
        current->engword = strdup(temp->spanword);
        printf("translated: %s\n", current->engword);
        current = current->next;
        
        /* We will clean the span list once everything is replaced */
        temp1 = temp; /* Store temp so we can free the memory once we advance */
        temp = temp->next;
        if (temp1->spanword != NULL)
            free(temp1->spanword);
        free(temp1);
    }
}
```